# Java string.format() only half working

Tags: java, string, format

I am trying to construct a string using string.format(), but it stops working (just over) half way through.

```
private String constructMessage(String messageType, int messageCode,Position location) {
    double lat = location.getLat();
    double lon = location.getLon();
    double ele = location.getEle();
    double speed = 0.0;
    double heading = 0.0;

    String msg = "$PNGVEST," + messageType + "," + VEST_ID + ","
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + "," + lat + "," + lon + "," + ele
            + "," + speed + "," + heading + "," + messageCode;

    String test = String.format("$PNGVEST,%s,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,$f,$f,$d",
            messageType, VEST_ID, System.currentTimeMillis(), lat, lon, ele,
            speed, heading, messageCode);

    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println(test);
    return msg;
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1439998967553,51.558641765246364,-3.043043462354341,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0
$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1439998967553,51.558642,-3.043043,-1.000000,$f,$f,$d
$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1439998968553,51.55862560874394,-3.043027770590568,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0
$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1439998968553,51.558626,-3.043028,-1.000000,$f,$f,$d
```

Why does it not format the last 3 variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made typo's with your last 3 variables. You noted `$f` and `$d` instead of `%f` and `%d`.

It should be :

```
String test = String.format("$PNGVEST,%s,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%d",
        messageType, VEST_ID, System.currentTimeMillis(), lat, lon, ele,
        speed, heading, messageCode);
```

Instead of

```
String.format("$PNGVEST,%s,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,$f,$f,$d", ...);
```

Comment: What a fresh set of eyes can do. It even took me about a minute to notice what you had even changed.

Comment: Such typo's are indeed hard to see, however the `$` signs in the output should have alarmed you ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
String test = String.format("$PNGVEST,%s,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,$f,$f,$d",
        messageType, VEST_ID, System.currentTimeMillis(), lat, lon, ele,
        speed, heading, messageCode);
```

to

```
String test = String.format("$PNGVEST,%s,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%d",
        messageType, VEST_ID, System.currentTimeMillis(), lat, lon, ele,
        speed, heading, messageCode);
```